# How to read ATOM XML in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, atom-feed

How to call System.ServiceModel.Syndication.SyndicationFeed from PowerShell?

I was trying to read RSS feed from Powershell, and need to traverse through feed, I am wondering what would be the way to do it?

I could not find any example on it.

Thanks in advance!!
Ramani

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I came up with in a few seconds:

```
$url = "http://stackoverflow.com/feeds/question/10589059"
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.ServiceModel") | Out-Null
[System.ServiceModel.Syndication.SyndicationFeed] $feed = [System.ServiceModel.Syndication.SyndicationFeed]::Load([System.Xml.XmlReader]::Create($url))
$feed | Get-Member
```

Comment: I got below error with above code,could you take a look at please?                                Unable to find type [System.ServiceModel.Syndication.SyndicationFeed]: make sure that the assembly containing this type is loaded.
At line:7 char:108
+ [System.ServiceModel.Syndication.SyndicationFeed] $feed = [System.ServiceModel.Syndication.SyndicationFeed] <<<< ::Load([System.Xml.XmlReader]::Create($URI))
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.ServiceM...SyndicationFeed:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TypeNotFound

Comment: Is System.ServiceModel installed in your GAC?  What happens when you run this line alone    [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.ServiceModel")

Comment: it works fine when I execute [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.ServiceModel") this line alsone

Comment: Do you have the .net 4.0 framework installed?  The assembly System.ServiceModel may have been a part of an earlier framework version, but System.ServiceMidel.Syndication.SyndicationFeed is part of .net 4.0.

Answer (score 4):

What you're really trying to do is parse XML with PowerShell.  This one liner will get you the entries from this question:

```
((New-Object Net.Webclient).DownloadString("http://stackoverflow.com/feeds/question/10589059") -as [xml]).feed.entry
```

It creates a new webclient, and downloads the URL, turns it into XML, and then just dots into the XML elements (as you can do in PowerShell).

It's a very simple one liner that packs in a lot of the power of PowerShell.  A similar example is at the beginning of Bruce Payette's "PowerShell In Action"

Hope this Helps